# How can I set a different ID for a column name?

Tags: java, playframework

To be specific, I have these codes in Java (Class A and class B):

```
//Class A
package models;
import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import play.db.ebean.Model;

@Entity
@Table(name="A")
public class A extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="id_a_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="id_a_seq", sequenceName="id_a_seq")
    @Column(name="ID_A", insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Integer id;

    @Column(name="NOME")
    public String nome;

    @Column(unique = true, name="CPF")
    public String cpf;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="A_B", 
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ID_A")}, 
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ID_B")})
    public List<B> lista = new ArrayList<B>();
}
```

```
//Class B
package models;
import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import play.db.ebean.Model;

@Entity
@Table(name="B")
public class B extends Model {

    public B() {}
    public B(Integer id, String nome) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="id_b_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="id_b_seq", sequenceName="id_b_seq")
    //@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "ID_B"))
    @Column(name="ID_B", insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Integer id;

    @Column(name="NOME")
    public String nome;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="lista")
    public List<A> lista = new ArrayList<A>();
}
```

When I run localhost:9000 in the browser, I get this error message:

"PersistenceException: Error with the Join on [models.B.lista]. Could not find the local match for [ID_B] Perhaps an error in a @JoinColumn".

I could solve this problem renaming ID_A and ID_B to ID (for both), but I can't have the name ID for the id columns (in table A and in table B). I need to figure out how to make Play to accept the ID_A and ID_B names for their id column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the mapping on your `lista` relationship to:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "A_B",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ID_A", referencedColumnName = "ID_A")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ID_B", referencedColumnName = "ID_B")})
public List<B> lista = new ArrayList<B>();
```

Note the addition of `referencedColumnName` to `@JoinColumn`.

[`referencedColumnName`](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/JoinColumn/referencedColumnName)  reference:

> When used inside a JoinTable annotation, the referenced key column is in the entity table of  the owning entity, or inverse entity if the join is part of the inverse join definition.

Comment: No problem. If you think I've answered your question properly, could you accept it? Thanks